# Almacenar un valor dentro de una variable que no es constante

Tags: java, netbeans, condiciones, datos, variables-de-configuración

Quiero que la variable `saldoactual` guarde el valor que se le da al hacer un deposito o al hacer un retiro y que no me guarde solo la cantidad por defecto.

```
public void condicional() {

        int cad = Integer.parseInt(graicos.txt_opcion.getText());
        int opc = cad;
        int saldoactual = 1000, total = 0;
        int v = 0;

        while (v == 0) {
            switch (opc) {

                case 1:

                    int retiro = Integer.parseInt(graicos.txt_Ingreso.getText());
                    total = saldoactual - retiro;
                    graicos.lbl_result.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                    break;
                case 2:

                    graicos.lbl_result.setText(String.valueOf(saldoactual));
                    break;

                case 3:
                    int dep = Integer.parseInt(graicos.txt_Ingreso.getText());
                    total = saldoactual + dep;
                    graicos.lbl_result.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Si entendí bien, lo único que debes hacer es sustituir donde quieras que tengas la variable `total`, sustituirla por `saldoactual`. Eso hará lo que quieres. Ej: `saldoactual = saldoactual - retiro;`

Comment: No me funciono La variable saldoactual inicia en 1000 pero al restarle  200 hace bien la operacion resta pero al querer consultar el saldo me muestra los 1000 que tiene la variable , no modifica su valor

Comment: edle777 para que persista, tienes que guardar la variable como un atributo de tu clase fuera del método actual. Es obvio que cada vez que llames al método estás redefiniendo la variable y poniéndole nuevamente el valor de 1000.

Comment: Lo que hice fue quitar el while pero al quitarlo la misma historia me da , si al agregar de nueva manera el while me hace el recorrido y me guarda el valor ? o ya lo modifica sacandolo del metodo

Comment: Simplemente saca `int saldoactual = 1000`, declaralo una línea antes si quieres  y haz el cambio que te dije en mi primer comentario. Lo demás por lo que se ve, puede quedarse como está.

Answer (score 0):

Le coloque

```
saldoactual=saldoactual-retiro; //y 
saldoactual=saldoactual-retiro;
```

para que ahora si los tome, saludos.

Quedaria asi:

```
    public void condicional() {

    int cad = Integer.parseInt(graicos.txt_opcion.getText());
    int opc = cad;
    int saldoactual = 1000, total = 0;
    int v = 0;

    while (v == 0) {
        switch (opc) {

            case 1:

                int retiro = Integer.parseInt(graicos.txt_Ingreso.getText());
                total = saldoactual - retiro;
                saldoactual=saldoactual-retiro;
                graicos.lbl_result.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                break;
            case 2:

                graicos.lbl_result.setText(String.valueOf(saldoactual));
                break;

            case 3:
                int dep = Integer.parseInt(graicos.txt_Ingreso.getText());
                total = saldoactual + dep;
                saldoactual=saldoactual+dep;
                graicos.lbl_result.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                break;

            case 4:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
        }

    
}
    
}
```

Comment: Al reves quedará mas elegante y se entenderá mejor el propósito: saldoactual = saldoactual - retiro; total = saldoactual; Además ya se puede inferir que quizá la veriable total sea equivalente a saldoactual y no haga nada.